# subscribe + forEach issue

Tags: angular, typescript, loops, foreach, subscribe

My code is like that :

```
this.service.getBusinessCtxValuesFromBizCtx(this.bizCtx.bizCtxId)
   .subscribe(values => {
      values.forEach(value => {
        this.service.getSimpleContextSchemeByCtxSchemeValuesId(value.ctxSchemeValueId)
          .subscribe(scheme => {
             console.log('Name of the Scheme : ' + scheme.schemeName);
        });
     });
});
```

Here is my issue :

The first service `ID = 3` retrieves a list `ID = 189, 12 and 18`, I get the complete list with the correct information  on picture.

However on the `forEach`, only the first element of the list is retrieved, the rest is `null`.
I can't find the reason behind this weird behavior.

[image]

Comment: You mean to say in the second foreach it is only logging the first element of the `schemes` array even though there are more elements in the array?

Comment: have you log the before 2nd `forEach`? Or else can you create SlackBlitz. Moreover, you are facing this issue because of `async` nature.

Comment: I edited my question with a picture

Comment: I tried a simple rxjs with nested observables, and it worked, so it must be something else you have not shared with us

Comment: So it s possible to use forEach and subscribe at the same times twice ? I thought there was an async issue related to that

Comment: And actually it is working fine, it retrieved the good information, it is just that it only returned the proper information for the first element of the array.

Comment: Can you please add a `console.log(JSON.stringify(values))` inside the callback for the first `subscribe`, then a `console.log(JSON.stringify(value))` inside the first `forEach`, and a `console.log(JSON.stringify(value))` in the callback for the second `subscribe`. Note that's a log of the `value` variable in that last `subscribe`.

Comment: The first subscribe retrieves correctly the whole list (189,12,18), However the second subscribe only retrieves the first value (189) and null for the 2 others

Comment: To be more precise, inside the for each there are the 3 values but within the scope of the 2nd subscribe only the first one is displayed

Comment: I wanted to delete this post since there were no helpful  answers in order to avoid ppl to not lose time on looking at this post. I did not mean to vandalizing it.